# Importing multiple objects with ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, object, inputstream

After implementing the suggestions I was given on my last post, I now have a working piece of code without any error messages, but my code will still only print the first object from my file. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Mainclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream("or.rtf");
            
            ObjectInputStream ois;
            try {
                
                int l = 1;
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
                
                while (l > 0) {
                    
                        
                    try {
                        
                        Stone p = (Stone) ois.readObject();
                        System.out.println(p);
                        
                        
                    }   catch(Exception e) {
                            if(e instanceof EOFException) {
                                l--;
                                System.err.println();
                            } else if(e instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
                                l--;
                                System.err.println(e);
                            } else {
                                System.err.println(e);
                            }
                    }
                }
                ois.close();
                    
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Code to save objects to a file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Saver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ArrayList<Stone> objects = new ArrayList<Stone>();
        objects.add(new Stone("Max",50,90));
        objects.add(new Stone("Fiona",30,60));
        objects.add(new Stone("Sam",20,30));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++ ) {
        
        
            try {
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("qt.rtf");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
            oos.writeObject(objects.get(i));
            System.out.println(i);
            oos.close();
        }   catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented the println(i) to check whether the code was even executed in a loop.

Comment: How did you create the file?  We'd need to see the code that created the file as well. You may have written only one object to the file.

Comment: Edited to add that file as well

Comment: So what debugging have you done? Have you stepped through the code in your IDE?  What did you find?  We would need to also see the code for `Stone`.  Your best bet is to spend some time debugging, and when you find where the program deviates from your expectations, ask a specific question about that deviation.

Comment: Could you point me towards documentation for doing so in eclipse?

Comment: What happens if you type "eclipse debugging tutorial" into a search engine?  One of the most important skills a developer can have is knowing how to find information.

Comment: I take your point

Comment: You are rewriting your file for each object, so I would expect that only the *last* object would be present.

Comment: You would be correct in that assessment, is the "oos.writeObject" line what is causing this? And if so, do you have an idea for a potential solution?

Comment: try changing the loop so that the creation of the `ObjectOutputStream` is outside and only `oos.writeObject(objects.get(i));` is inside of the loop.

Comment: I may have it now, moved the streams outside into a "try" and embedded the loop just after that. Thank you kindly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the scope of `ObjectOutputStream` and `FileOutputStream`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Stone> objects = new ArrayList<Stone>();
        objects.add(new Stone("Max",50,90));
        objects.add(new Stone("Fiona",30,60));
        objects.add(new Stone("Sam",20,30));

        try {
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("qt.rtf");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++ ) {
                oos.writeObject(objects.get(i));
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You are also not reading from the same file you created `or.rtf` and `qr.rtf`.